# Rotativa locally works fine but it's unable to redirect the view in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

Rotativa locally works fine but it's unable to redirect to the desired view to print in the server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmwHC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check here:

1. Rotativa uses wkhtmltopdf, check if it is installed on server.
2. you can just copy the 2 following dll files to the Rotativa folder (in root location of project) on the server if you don't want to / can't easily install things on the server, i.e., msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll

Check similar question/answers here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50066692/3559462

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877635/3559462

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942678/3559462

(razor to pdf using rotativa or itextsharp): https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp.net/export-html-to-pdf-in-aspnet-mvc-using-itextsharp-or-rotativ/94

I recommend you add "Rotativa" folder in the root of your application and add these files

```
help-wkhtmltoimage.txt
help-wkhtmltopdf.txt
msvcp120.dll
msvcp140.dll
msvcr120.dll
vcruntime140.dll
wkhtmltoimage.exe
wkhtmltopdf.exe
wkhtmltox.dll
```

As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711643/3559462